# Asp.net MVC - Create environment specific Meta tag in cshtml page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

To block staging URL from google search result, advised to include below line of code in cshtml page head section. But when I add this line of code in head section, it will be moved to Production environment too.

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
```

Here my question is, how to create environment specific meta tags. I want this code only in staging and not in Production. How to implement that in Asp.Net MVC3 application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add environment type to the web.config in the appSettings:

```
  <appSettings>
   <add key="env" value="test"/>
</appSettings>
```

and in the cshtml file check if the environment is test add the meta

```
@if (System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["env"] == "test")
{
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
}
```